# Реализуйте рекурсивный алгоритм вычисления суммы n первых членов ряда

Tags: c#, рекурсия, ряды

Реализуйте рекурсивный алгоритм вычисления суммы n первых членов ряда. Вычисление факториала и возведение в степень для каждого члена ряда нельзя использовать.

1+(x/1!)+(x^2/2!)+(x^3/3!)+...+(x^n/n!)

```
double recursive_f(double n, double x)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {

    }
    else
    {
            
    }

    return s;              
}
```

Вообще не понимаю как... Я могу только рекурсивно вычислить факториал.
Нужно рекурсивно (через цикл я и сам могу) вычислить сумму, при этом вычисление факториала и возведение в степень для каждого члена ряда нельзя использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Если под суммой, например, трёх первых членов ряда имеется в виду со включением третьей степени: `1+(x/1!)+(x^2/2!)+(x^3/3!)`, то

```
def req(x, n, current = 1, p = 1):
    if p > n:
        return current
    else:
        return current + req(x, n, current * x / p, p + 1)

print(req(0.5, 3))
```

Код на Питоне, шарп негде проверить сейчас, но перевести легко

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с использованием `ref` параметра для возврата суммы, основная функция вычисляет и возвращает `x^n/n!`:

```cs
public static double Calc(double x, int n) {
    double s = 0;
    Calc(x, n, ref s);
    Console.WriteLine($"Calc ({x}, {n}) -> {s}");
    return s;
}

public static double Calc(double x, int n, ref double s) {
    if (n == 0) {
        s = 1;
        return 1;
    }
    double p = x/n * Calc(x, n - 1, ref s);
    s += p;
    return p;
}
```

Тест:

```cs
Calc(1, 0);
Calc(1, 1);
Calc(6, 4);
```

```
Calc (1, 0) -> 1
Calc (1, 1) -> 2
Calc (6, 4) -> 115
```

---

Если же переписать обычное итерационное решение:

```cs
public static double Iter(double x, int n) {
    double sum = 1;
    double p = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        p *= x / i;
        sum += p;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

в "прямом" порядке, то получится аналог [ответа @MBo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1507051/386633):

```cs
static double Rec(double x, int n, double sum = 1, int i = 1) {
    return i > n ? sum : sum + Rec(x, n, sum * x / i, i + 1);
}
```